# how to move wordpress short code button to the center of the page, please?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

this is how short code looks like

[stripe name="My Store" description="My Product" amount="1999" billing="true" shipping="true"]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpZVL.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a div tag:

```
<div id="button>"[stripe name="My Store" description="My Product" amount="1999" billing="true" shipping="true"]</div>

<style>
#button {
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
}
</style>
```